# Here-API: negative distance in reverse geo coding

Tags: here-api

I'm using the (multi-request) reverse geo coding from the HERE-API and request landmarks (in the end I want to find out if a position is above water). Everything works nicely, but I quite often get negative distances to a landmark (especially when the landmark is a river):

```
{'Distance': -86.3,
 'Location': {'Address': {'AdditionalData': [{'key': 'CountryName',
                                              'value': 'United States'},
                                             {'key': 'StateName',
                                              'value': 'New York'}],
                          'Country': 'USA',
                          'Label': 'NY, United States',
                          'State': 'NY'},
              'DisplayPosition': {'Latitude': 40.75038, 'Longitude': -73.95749},
              'LocationId': 'NT_AkVytIiMG.HuEjq23NLorC',
              'LocationType': 'river',
              'MapReference': {'CountryId': '21000001',
                               'PlaceId': '35543547',
                               'StateId': '21010819'},
              'MapView': {'BottomRight': {'Latitude': 40.68625,
                                          'Longitude': -73.79247},
                          'TopLeft': {'Latitude': 40.8145,
                                      'Longitude': -74.01498}},
              'Name': 'East River'},
 'MatchLevel': 'landmark',
 'MatchQuality': {'Country': 1.0, 'Name': 1.0, 'State': 1.0},
 'Relevance': 1.0}
```

Can someone tell me how I should interpret this distance?

Answer (score 1):

The distance for Reverse Geocoder admin area results is calculated from the supplied point to the
polygon boundary. The distance is therefore negative, where the specified point is inside the area.
This is aligned with landmark results. With gen<6, the distance for admin area results is calculated
from the specified point to the center of the area.

Comment: That was fast :) Does that mean that I should check for negative distances if I want to know if my location is within a river or lake?

Comment: no, this refers to the bounding box, not the river shape.